# How to get the -Repository functionality in VS2013 asp.net scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, repository-pattern, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

In the old version of mvc scaffolding that could be installed via nuget, there was a switch for the Scaffold Controller command called -Repository.  This used the repository pattern in the generated code for easier unit testing.   In the new version of Scaffolding that is now part of Visual Studio 2013, the package manager command line is gone, and now everything is done through context menus.   For example: Add, New Scaffolded Item, MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework.

But I don't see anything in the new dialog to tell it to use the Repository pattern.

My questions are these: 
Is there a way to use the repository pattern using the new VS2013 scaffolding?
If not do I just manually add the repository pattern to my code?
Or is there some other way I should do my unit testing that doesn't involve the repository pattern?

Also if I manually add the repository pattern to my code, won't I have to re-add it every time I regenerate the scaffolded code?

Comment: Did you ever get a response to this or figure out if there is an automatic way of doing this?